# Adding CXXFlag into dpkg-buildpackage

Tags: debian-packaging, dpkg-buildpackage

I am creating .deb package from source `.tar.gz` I have done all the steps, and at last I ran this command `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -F` to build the package, at the final step during linking error is thrown with message `undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5` which means I need to add `-pthread` to compiler flag, but I dont understand how to add this I tried to documents of `dpkg-buildflags` but they are very confusing and I m not able to understand how to do this.

`debian/rule` file

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1

# see FEATURE AREAS in dpkg-buildflags(1)
#export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all
#DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
#include /usr/share/dpkg/buildflags.mk
# see ENVIRONMENT in dpkg-buildflags(1)
# package maintainers to append CFLAGS
#export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
# package maintainers to append LDFLAGS
#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed

override_dh_auto_configure:
        env | sort
        dh_auto_configure --buildsystem=cmake -- -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE:BOOL=true -DHUNTER_ENABLED=OFF
%:
        dh $@


# dh_make generated override targets
# This is example for Cmake (See https://bugs.debian.org/641051 )
#override_dh_auto_configure:
#       dh_auto_configure -- #  -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so I got the answer, uncomment this
`export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic -pthread` and this `#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed -pthread`
this will add the flag `-pthread`